# Updating a string with items in a list in java8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a string and would like alter the string based on the list content.

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
       lst.add("</lldp>");
       lst.add("</ftp>");
       lst.add("</snmp>");

       String text2 = "The cefcFRURemoved notification </snmp>";
       for(String str: lst) {
           text2 = text2.replaceAll(str, "");
       }
```

I would like to find an equivalent approach to do the same using java8 stream.

```
**Something like : tagList.stream().map((e) ->  text.replaceAll(e, "")).collect(Collectors.joining())**
```

of course this is entirely wrong way of doing. But i am trying to find stream approach to do the same

Answer (score 1):

```
String p = lst.stream()
              .map(Pattern::quote)
              .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));

String text2 = "The cefcFRURemoved notification </snmp>";
System.out.println(text2.replaceAll(p, ""));
```

Or you could concat all patterns you care about and simply do a `replaceAll`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use this instead of stream:

```
text2 = text2.replaceAll(String.join("|", lst), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    final List<String> lst = Arrays.asList("</lldp>", "</ftp>", "</snmp>");

    final String text2 = "The cefcFRURemoved notification </snmp>";

    /*
     * sequential() is important here. If you run in parallel() instead,
     * the code will fail.
     */
    final String result = lst.stream().sequential()
                             .map(Pattern::quote)
                             .map(Pattern::compile)
                             .reduce(text2,
                                     (input, pattern) -> pattern.matcher(input).replaceAll(""),
                                     (left, right) -> {
                                         /*
                                          * Never invoked for sequential streams.
                                          */
                                         throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format("left=\"%s\"; right=\"%s\"", left, right));
                                     });
    System.out.println(result);
```